# LARAVEL 5.5 - modificar tamaño maximo de archivos de subida

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, fileupload

en mi sistema de laravel solo me deja subir archivos de hasta 2MB.
¿como puedo cambiar este limite?
¿puedo hacerlo solo desde laravel o esto esta limitado por apache o PHP?

Comment: Normalmente está limitado por el servidor y PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Está limitado por php, pero puedes cambiarlo en el php.ini modificando las siguientes líneas por un valor más alto:

```
upload_max_filesize = 40M
post_max_size = 40M
```