# laravel no me permite subir archivos superiores a 1MB

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hola compañeros necesito ayuda. tengo que subir unas imagenes al servidor pero estas imagenes son muy pesadas.

tengo mis validaciones personalizadas

```
$rules = array
(
'comprobante' => 'required',
'comprobante.*' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:100'
);
$messages = array
(
'comprobante.required' => 'La imagen del comprobante es obligado',
'comprobante.image' => 'Debe ser una imagen',
'comprobante.max' => 'Archivo muy pesado para subirlo',
);

$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $messages);
if ($validator->fails())
{
return redirect()>back()>withInput()>withErrors($validator)>withInput();

}else{
try {

if (!empty($request->comprobante)) {
$imageName = date('YmdHis').'.'.$request->comprobante->getClientOriginalExtension();
$request->comprobante->move(public_path('uploads/comprobantes/'), $imageName);
$requestData['comprobante'] = 'uploads/comprobantes/'.'-'.$imageName;
}

alert()>success('Registrado correctamente!')>autoclose(6000);
$comprobante = Voucher::create($requestData);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
alert()>warning('No se pudo realizar su etición corretamente!')>autoclose(6000);
}
}
```

este es el codigo que utilizo pero al subir archivos pequeños como de 1MB de 1668 x 1231 de dimenciones. este lo sube correctamente pero cuanto lo intento con una imagen de 4.67MB DE 3456 X 4608 solo me muestra el error `The comprobante failed to upload.` ni siquiera me muestra la validacion personalizada que tengo, como lo puedo hacer me ayudan? lo importante es que se suba el archivo mas pesado.

codigo: https://paste.laravel.io/a7ddd532-e139-492d-8545-952cc933dc84

Comment: hola , creo que ese se configura en el php.ini , mira este [LINK](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/108849/laravel-5-5-modificar-tama%C3%B1o-maximo-de-archivos-de-subida)

Comment: Te faltó agregarle la regla del tamaño a la imagen. La puedes declarar de está manera `'image' => 'file|size:5000';` recuerda que esto se maneja por kb.

Answer (score 0):

Necesita cambiar los valores de `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` en tu php.ini

```
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 40M

; Must be greater than or equal to upload_max_filesize
post_max_size = 40M
```